# c# SQL search button click event that populates into text boxes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to map a SQL database query to pull the query from a text box via a click event on a search button, and display the results in other text boxes on the same form.

But now I'm stuck. I either get no result, or an unhandled exception. I have been up and down google and SO, and I am not sure where to go next with this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;


namespace EmployeeEvaluation
{
public partial class frmOpenRead : Form
{
    public frmOpenRead()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // QUIT BUTTON
        Close();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // THIS IS THE SEARCH BUTTON
        string conString = @"Data Source=SQL1;Initial Catalog=EE;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(conString);

        string selectSql = "SELECT *  FROM   tbl_TextBoxes   where   [Ename]  =  @Ename";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectSql, sc);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ename", txtBoxSearch.Text);

        try
        {
            sc.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    textBox1.Text = (read["Ename"].ToString());
                    textBox2.Text = (read["Sname"].ToString());
                    textBox4.Text = (read["PositionUpdateBox"].ToString());
                    textBox5.Text = (read["PerFac1"].ToString());
                    textBox7.Text = (read["PerFac2"].ToString());
                    textBox10.Text = (read["PerFac3"].ToString());
                    textBox11.Text = (read["PerFac4"].ToString());
                    textBox12.Text = (read["PerFac5"].ToString());
                    textBox16.Text = (read["PerFac6"].ToString());
                    textBox17.Text = (read["PerFac7"].ToString());
                    textBox18.Text = (read["PerFac8"].ToString());
                    textBox22.Text = (read["PerFac9"].ToString());
                    textBox24.Text = (read["PerFac10"].ToString());
                    textBox25.Text = (read["PerFac11"].ToString());
                    textBox28.Text = (read["PerFac12"].ToString());
                    textBox30.Text = (read["PerFac13"].ToString());
                    textBox3.Text = (read["EvalDate"].ToString());
                    textBox6.Text = (read["Rating1"].ToString());
                    textBox8.Text = (read["Rating2"].ToString());
                    textBox13.Text = (read["Rating3"].ToString());
                    textBox14.Text = (read["Rating4"].ToString());
                    textBox15.Text = (read["Rating5"].ToString());
                    textBox19.Text = (read["Rating6"].ToString());
                    textBox20.Text = (read["Rating7"].ToString());
                    textBox21.Text = (read["Rating8"].ToString());
                    textBox23.Text = (read["Rating9"].ToString());
                    textBox26.Text = (read["Rating10"].ToString());
                    textBox27.Text = (read["Rating11"].ToString());
                    textBox29.Text = (read["Rating12"].ToString());
                    textBox31.Text = (read["Rating13"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }

    }

    private void frmOpenRead_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'eEDataSetTextBoxes.tbl_TextBoxes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tbl_TextBoxesTableAdapter.Fill(this.eEDataSetTextBoxes.tbl_TextBoxes);

    }

    private void txtBoxSearch_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxSearch.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void startOverButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // START OVER BUTTON CLEARS CONTENT OF ALL TEXT BOXES
        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox4.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox5.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox7.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox10.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox11.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox12.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox16.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox17.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox18.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox22.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox24.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox25.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox28.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox30.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox3.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox6.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox8.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox13.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox14.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox15.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox19.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox20.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox21.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox23.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox26.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox27.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox29.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox31.Text = String.Empty;
    }

        private void txtBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here are a few places I have looked at first when making what I have so far, in addition to a few youtube videos on c# w/ SQL:

[Get data from sql query into textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761545/get-data-from-sql-query-into-textbox)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984467(v=vs.71).aspx

Can anyone show me where I have gone wrong here, or point me toward a resource or two that might help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are getting a exception you should really click the [Copy exception details to clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) and paste the info here. We can't help you if you don't tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: Is there an error happening here? Make sure there is data returned. textBox6.Text = (read["Rating1"].ToString()); for example should work unless the query result is empty

Comment: Which code line is throwing error?

Answer (score 1):

Let `X` be a column having `null` in the query result. So the `read["X"]` will also be `null`. we are not supposed to convert the null to an Empty string. SO what you need to do is, change the assignment statement like the following:

```
textBoxN.Text = read["X"]==null||read["X"]==DBNull?"":read["X"].ToString();
```

Comment: SqlDataReader will never contain null, and DBNull.ToString() returns empty by default. I doubt this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed == to = on one of my sql strings before pasting here, and that stopped the exception. Up until now, when I did this, the result also was that the button click did nothing.

I have been up and down google for a week now, and even gave up for a day or two. I swore I wasn't going to post to SO, I was going to figure it out myself. Then I broke down and posted to SO, ran my code again, and now it works. Yes I am a novice. First post here actually. So I guess the issue is resolved but I can't say I changed anything, just gave it time?

Thanks for the responses everyone.